Proving Measurability of $ f(x) = \begin{cases} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) & \text{if the limit exists,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $
Question:
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Define
$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) & \text{if the limit exists,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$
Prove that $f$ is measurable.
(Hint: Let $A = \{x : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \text{ exists}\}$. Define $g = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \chi_A$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. Then show that $f = g$. Why does this imply $f$ is measurable?)
Attempted Solution:
I tried to show the measurability of $f$ by proving that $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is measurable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Specifically, I found that:
$
f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty} f_k^{-1}\left(\left(a + \frac{1}{j}, \infty\right)\right),
$
which suggests that $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is measurable.
However, I'm not sure how to connect this approach with the hint provided in the problem, specifically with defining $A$ and $g$ as suggested. Is this solution correct, and how how to solve it using the hint of $f$?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I haven't tried to work out your logic, but the fact that you have the same expression for $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ whether $a \ge 0$ or $a < 0$ seems highly suspicious.
